# Boost Dijkstra with multiple start and end nodes

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

When using [Lemon](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) it is possible to run Dijkstra with multiple sources -- in my case always two start and two end nodes -- and stop early once any of the targets is reached.
For example, the following code works nice for me:

```
template<class Graph, class Node, class CostMap>
double shortestPath(Node from1, Node from2, Node to1, Node to2,
                    const Graph &graph, const CostMap &costs)
{
    lemon::Dijkstra<Graph, CostMap> dijkstra(graph, costs);
    dijkstra.init();
    dijkstra.addSource(from1);
    dijkstra.addSource(from2);

    while (!dijkstra.emptyQueue())
    {
        dijkstra.processNextNode();
        if (dijkstra.processed(to1) || dijkstra.processed(to2))
            return ...;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Now I wonder how I can do the same thing with the BGL.

So far I implemented the early stopping via throwing an exception once any of the to nodes is reached as is described in the [BGL FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/faq.html).
I still struggle with the multiple sources part and unfortunately the BGL docs are not very helpful.
This [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-devel-archive/g9F7bRyyi80) hints that people at least thought of the issue, though it appears nothing was implemented yet.

Is this possible with BGL?

Comment: I don't think BGL allows this AFAIK. Exposing this type of information about the search queue is not something that BGL favors. They would rather encapsulate it. You could try a custom Dijkstra visitor but that may be a hassle/overkill. I would just suggest running Dijkstra twice. You mileage may vary but Dijkstra is pretty fast in BGL from my experience.